# Couldn't publish apps on play store

Tags: google-play-console, playback

I create my developer account and buy a google play store account 2 to 3 months behind but now when I open my account this error show on my account dashboard,
"Your ID couldn’t be verified, We couldn’t verify your ID, so you won’t be able to publish apps on Google Play from this account"
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You probably need to verify your ID. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9198012

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have submitted the documents my verification is failed.
How can i reapply?

Comment: Then you can contact support at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/idv_form

Answer (score 1):

I am basing my answer on this [support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9198012#zippy=):

If necessary, submit your application again, bearing in mind the following tips, directly quoted:

- Capture the entire document in the photo. It should be readable and in focus. Do not crop the image - all four corners of the document should be contained within the image.
- Keep your image free of reflections and glare. Turn off the flash.
- Incomplete documents or dark or blurry photos won't be accepted.
- You'll be allowed a limited number of verification attempts.
- Uploading files other than an image of your ID may result in account suspension.

You can also check the [status of your application](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/#AppListPlace).  If that doesn't state the reason clearly, you can [contact support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/idv_form).